# Java opening file form actual user home with ~/

Tags: java, linux

Is there a way in java to open file form actual user home using ~/ operator? I was trying to do it using File, but this searching for file in Users/user/payara5/glassfish/domains/pool/config/~/test.png directory.

```
File file = new File("~/test.png");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is behaving completely correct. `~` has no special meaning in a filename or path, it is simply a legal character like any other. `~` is a perfectly valid name for a file or directory, therefore `~/test.png` simply means "a file named `test.png` in a subdirectory named `~` of the current working directory".

`~` is a feature of some *shells*, but not a feature of the OS, filenames, or Java.

Note also that the concept of "home directory" is not universally portable. For example, it does not exist on Windows and most mobile platforms.

The most reliable and most portable way to get the user's home directory (assuming such a thing even exists) is

```java
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

This might give non-sensical results on Windows, but that's simply because the concept of "home directory" does not exist on Windows.

Comment: To cmplement Jorg's answer, I'll add that you should modify your code like this: `File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.png");` to create a a file "test.png" in the home directory.